# Issue with EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, pull-to-refresh

When I use the EGOTableViewPullRefresh just like its demo

```
- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource
{
      _reloading = YES;
      sleep(10);//something just like reload the data,here is a simple example
}

- (void)egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view
{
      [self reloadTableViewDataSource];
      [self performSelector:@selector(doneLoadingTableViewData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

There's a problem where it doesn't change state to EGOOPullRefreshLoading when `sleep(10)`,so there still is the arrow down and the title is "Pull down to refresh " when reload data.

How can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, because in their demo app says that something like reloading the data should be put in `- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource`, but instead I tried to put that inside `- (void)egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view` & everything work perfect.

So my advice would be to put `sleep(10);` before `[self reloadTableViewDataSource];`